# How do I get the type of an ID (User, Page, App, etc.)

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I didn't find any answer in the API Documentation and also not in the SDK.

If I use "/me/home" for example, I will get my news feed. The news feed contains entries from users, pages, apps, etc. But how do I know wheather an entry is from a user, page or app? In the output there is no information about the type. All entries have a ID and no more information about the type behind the ID.

Answer (score 0):

i donot know i am correct but you may check that if link in your dynamic variable you are using contains "app." then it is from application and if it is from page then there should be category information  then it is from page or group .etc

I would try to be more clear if you provide some more detail what needs to be done?

Comment: Hm.. so in this case I still don't know wheather it is a page or group...  I'm developing a Facebook App and on the users wall or news feed there could be any kind of message (from users, apps, pages, etc.). If the users klick on a message, I want to show different UIs for each type (User profile, Fan Page, App, etc.)

Comment: well for this i will say you have to do(what i think) check the type.On the wall there is type in some posts posts that are posted by pages or groups they would have category tab in it.I think you really need to explore the string you get by placing it in watch and see what attributes are present there

Comment: with type i meant there is info in the data received that particular post is link or message etc

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! Thanks to the facebook developer forum!

Just add ?metadata=1 to the request and you will get a field "type" which has values like "page", "group", "user", etc.